# mySQL Left Join on multiple values (REPLACE AND SUBSTRING_INDEX FUNCTION failed)

Tags: mysql, csv, replace, substring, reporting

I am trying to join 2 tables `tbl_questions` and `tbl_answers`.

`tbl_questions` contains the qid and the answer columns
`tbl_answers` stores the answerid and answerdesc columns.

tbl_questions data stores the multiple choice answers by encapsulating it with ["answer"] and separated by a comma like this ["16672","16673","16676"] any none multiple choice answers are stored like this 16688.
I have to report on this data and cant do a join on any of the multiple choice questions, comes back blank understandably.

I have tried to run the following on the table

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(answer,'"',''),'[',''),']','') FROM tbl_questions
```

This cleans up the multiple choice answer to 16672,16673,16676
Then I separate the the answers using the comma with the following

```
SELECT Userid,SUBSTRING_INDEX(answer,',',1) as 'Option 1',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(answer,',',2),',',-1) AS 'Option 2',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(answer,',',-2),',',1) AS 'Option 3',
SUBSTRING_INDEX(answer,',',-1) AS 'Option 4'
FROM tbl_questions
```

This then creates new columns Option 1 - 4 but still doesn't solve my issue as the single answers appear in all new columns Option 1 -4.
I don't feel the route i was taking to solve the problem is going to work.
Does anyone know how i would join theses tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by trying to fix your schema and have a separate table to store each possible answer to each question, with one row per question/answer tuple. This would properly represent the relationship between your entites, and make the query much easier and efficient.

If th'at's not an option for you, then an alternative is `find_in_set()`:

```
select ...
from tbl_questions q
inner join tbl_answers a 
    on find_in_set(
        a.answer_id,
        replace(replace(replace(q.answer,'"',''),'[',''),']','') 
    )
```

You could also consider using JSON functions, since your string format is understandable by MySQL as such (this requires MySQL 5.7 or higher):

```
select ...
from tbl_questions q
inner join tbl_answers a 
    on json_contains(replace(replace(q.answer,'"',''), a.answer_id)
```

Comment: Thanks your first solution worked for me, I dont have control over the database, Im using it just to report on. Thanks

Comment: On the second statement, a parenthesis is missing somewhere ...